# How to absolutely obliterate a branch with a detached head in git?

Tags: git, github, merge

I am in a panic state.

I accidentally damaged a couple of branches and lost some work, but so far I still have hope. There is a single detached head that contains around 10 hours of work.

I damaged another one that had 12 hours of work trying to merge/restore a git branch to be just the info of the detached head.

Basically what I need/want is to take the current detached head, and force a branch to become character by character that detached head, no merging, no checks. The only thing that matters is that the branch becomes EXACTLY the detached head, without git trying to be smart abou it.

I then need to merge this obliterated branch with master.

Please help, 10 hours of work is quite a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to do, should be to *copy* the whole git repo/project;
then you can try anything and mess around while having a safe backup.

If you have access to `gitk`, you can use `gitk --all` to get a good overview
of all references in your tree, local, remote, and stashed commits, which may
show some assumed-lost references.

```
git checkout -b <new branch>
```

will create a new branch at the current commit or detached state.

You can then `git add -A` to make certain all (non-ignored) files get added and then
do an emergency commit on this new branch, to ensure you don't lose any uncommited
files when switching away from it.

`git reflog` is your friend. It may help you to get back to a previous state
which would otherwise be lost. (Have a backup first.)

To put this recovered detached HEAD branch onto master, you can use a
cherry-pick, rebase or merge.

```
git rebase --onto master recovered^ recovered
```

for example, would rebase a single commit in your branch `recovered` on top of `master`.

Comment: As long as it’s in git, you haven’t lost anything.

Comment: And with all the git magic, sometimes we forget it's just a directory we can copy. Once we realize that, it's often easier to do the deep magic (`reflog`, `filter-branch`) in a temp copy until we get it right. Just don't keep the copies around, multiple histories will get confusing later on! ;)

Answer (score 1):

First do a git status, to confirm there is no untracked files (and that HEAD is detached)

Then create a new branch from there:

```
git checkout -b tmp
```

Finally, you can reset any branch to it:

```
git checkout -B aBranch tmp
```

If you work (in this branch or the other one also damaged) was committed, you should be able to find both of those branches back in [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog).

Don't also forget to check your IDE: it can keep a local history of its own for your files. (For instance, [Visual Studio Code with this plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gayanhewa.local-history))